# How to cross-reference chapter as section

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I am using `cleveref` to cross-reference my thesis. When I use `\Cref` to reference chapter 1, in the text it appears as "Chapter 1". I was wondering if there I still use the chapter structure for the main text, but the cross-reference in the text will show as "Section 1" instead.

Comment: Is the name substitution ("chapter" -> "section") supposed to be global or just on a case by case base? Please advise.

Comment: It is supposed to be global

Answer (score 5):

If the name substitution is supposed to be *global*, you could employ the `\crefalias` device to achieve your objective. E.g.,

[image]

Asisde: I assume you are well aware of the fact that your readers may get confused if "chapters" are referred to as "sections."

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefalias{chapter}{section}

\begin{document}
\refstepcounter{chapter}\label{ch:1}
\refstepcounter{chapter}\label{ch:2}
Cross-references to \cref{ch:1,ch:2}.
\end{document}
```

---

If, on the other hand, the name substitution is supposed to apply to just a subset of chapters, e.g., the second chapter, you could set an optional argument for `\label` instruction associated with the chapter in question.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\refstepcounter{chapter}\label{ch:1}
\refstepcounter{chapter}\label[section]{ch:2}

Cross-references to \cref{ch:1,ch:2}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\crefname` to globally redefine the "name" used by [cleveref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/):

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{chapter}{section}{sections}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}\label{C:chapter}

  \Cref{C:chapter}  \cref{C:chapter}

\end{document}
```